# Function returns 'None' after reading file data, (only after FileNotFoundError exception is handled)

Tags: python, function, exception

I am a total beginner to Python, and am attempting the following exercise:

1) Write code to open and read a file

2) Allow the user to specify a filename

3) Add error handling to allow the user to try again if the file cannot be located

I have tried searching for any related questions prior to this but was unable to resolve the issue below:

```
import sys

def file_name():
    file_name = input("Please choose a filename you wish to open/read: ")
    return file_name

def file_reader(file_name):
    try:
        while file_name.find(".") < 0:
            file_name += ".txt"
        read_mode = "r"
        with open(file_name, read_mode) as file:
            output = "\n" + file.read() + "\n"
            return output
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("\nFILE NOT FOUND! Please try again.\n")
        print_contents()
    except:
        error = sys.exc_info()[0]
        print("Many apologies! Something has went wrong!")
        print(error)

def print_contents():
    print(file_reader(file_name()))

while True:
    print_contents()
```

Here, the function "file_reader(file_name)" concatenates ".txt" to the end of the user-specified filename where there is no file extension already specified, then attempts to read from the file.

In the event of a FileNotFoundError exception, this then prompts the user for another input. 
However, if the user then enters a valid filename after the exception, the file contents are returned, followed by 'None'.

I am very confused as to why 'None' is returned with the file contents ONLY ONCE after a FileNotFoundError exception has been handled, after which the 'while True' loop seems to work correctly again. How can I prevent 'None from being returned with the user-specified file data after a FileNotFoundError exception was previously handled?

As I am still very new to Python, any other constructive feedback is welcomed.

Comment: The function `print` doesn't return (explicitly) or in other words, returns `None`. You need to decide whether your functions `print` something, or return a value. If you just want them to `print`, you don't need to return

Comment: Thanks Tomerikoo, I have now removed all unnecessary instances of `return` where applicable, so that `return` and `print` do not occur on the same line as each other. However, I still appear to be getting the same issue?

Comment: That is because now your function `file_reader` returns `None` (from the `except` blocks) and then you print that in `print_contents`. I personnaly think recurssion is unnecessary here and really complicates things. You have 2 functions calling each other repeatedlly and that's recipe for confusion (as you noticed)

Comment: If you still want to leave it as it is, try changing to `print(output)` instead of return and then just `file_reader(file_name())` without the print